# jqueryUI multiple autocomplete using php/mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have tried searching but none of the results I found had an answer that works so I am hoping that maybe someone might have a suggestion (maybe the people who had the same issue as me found a solution and could share)

I have been trying to us http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote
However instead of having a hardcoded text array of potential results I want to search for the term from a mysql table.

My issue is the search result code does not work and instead throws an error that says
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')'

My code is

```
sleep( 3 );
// no term passed - just exit early with no response
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ;
$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
// remove slashes if they were magically added
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);

$items = array(
 $sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT first_name, last_name, email_addr FROM user_profiles
                     WHERE last_name LIKE '$q%'");
 while($sqlrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
 {
   extract($sqlrow);
   echo "'a $first_name $last_name'=>$email_addr',";
 }

);


$result = array();
foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
    array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
}
if (count($result) > 11)
    break;
}

// json_encode is available in PHP 5.2 and above, or you can install a PECL 
//module in earlier versions
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

The error line is the line that has the mysqli_query() I think its taking the ) and using it as the closing bracket for the array() 
I am not sure how to edit the above code so that when a user types in a value in the text box the autocomplete will work. I should note this code is suppose to enable me to have multiple autocomplete values within the same input box

thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing/commenting out the `);` at the end of the while loop?

Comment: yes but actually the $items = array( the was commented out was done so in error. When I uncomment the $items = array( line I get an error that says

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

So I my question becomes how do you put a mysql query inside am array() tag and get it to actually work?